# 32:9 Resolution using Xrandr on XPS 13 2020 developer Edition with Ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, xrandr, laptop, resolution

Hello StackExchange community, 
I recently got a Monitor with a resolution of 5120x1440 and I wondered whether it would be possible for me to add a new resolution with `xrandr`, as Ubuntu doesn't show me the option in the default ui.
I am using a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 18 LTS and a dongle also by Dell which has an HDMI Port (where i plugged in the monitor), LAN, VGA and USB. Adding the resolution worked as it should and the new set resolution also showed up in the Ubuntu ui as well as `arandr`. Here are the commands I used in order to get it to work: 
`$ gtf 5120 1440 60`
`$ xrandr --newmode "5120x1440_60.00"  623.65  5120 5488 6048 6976  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync`

- The "Modeline" returned by the `gtf` command

`$ xrandr --addmode DP-2 "5120x1440_60.00"`

- DP-2 is what is returned by `xrandr -q` as the secondary monitor (it also displays 21:9 as maximum which is the corresponding value from the Ubuntu ui)

I then proceeded to use `arandr` because my Laptop screen didn't display anything when using the Ubuntu ui (The Laptop display was flickering and only fragments of pictures were shown because Ubuntu seemed to have tried to merge both screens together.). When I tried setting the new resolution in `arandr`, i got the Error: 
`XRandR failed: XRandR returned error code 1: xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed`
I searched the internet for a resolution but didn't find anything useful to my situation.\

---

I tried to then use `cvt` instead of `gtf` because I ran out of ideas and using `cvt` was another solution i found:
`$ cvt -r 5120 1440 60`
Produced the Modeline:
`"5120x1440R"  469.00  5120 5168 5200 5280  1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync`
The other steps were basically the same as above and after using
`$ xrandr --addmode DP-2 "5120x1440R"`
(which should already set the new mode as the resolution for `DP-2`). I tried running 
`$ xrandr --output DP-2 --mode "5120x1440R"`
which returned
`xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed`
I couldn't really find anything on the internet which helped me understand this error, except for using `--verbose` as an option in order to get a more detailed output:\

```
crtc 1: 5120x1440_60.00  60.00 +0+0 "DP-2"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
```

---

I am kind of running out of ideas at this point. If it is somehow not possible to run at this resolution because of the technical limitations of the laptop, I would also be fine with running 21:9 ratio, but with black borders on the side, as the 21:9 is scaled up to the width of the screen and it is absolutely hideous. I however don't know how i would do anything similar and appreciate every tip you can give me.

---

---

System Specs:

- Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
- Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
- 15,3 GiB DDR4 Memory
- 500 GB SSD Storage